# Listening for messageReactionRemove for old reactions on old messages - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've written a discord.js bot and use a message's reactions to update my database on add or remove of a reaction.

I have everything working just fine by fetching the messages on client start and use **messageReactionAdd** and **messageReactionRemove**.

The issue is that by fetching the old message apparently I'm not fetching the message's old reactions so when a user removes the reaction right after the client's restart, nothing happens. If the user adds a reaction while the client is running and then remove it messageReactionRemove is working just fine.

How can I cache also the reactions of the fetched message so the **messageReactionRemove** gonna listen to the removal of an old reaction right after a restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is explained better [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2922).

The solution is either to use [partials](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/topics/partials.md) or to catch raw events, explanation for raw events by **AnIdiotsGuide**, [here](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md).